# Join one to many with multiple where

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

This is products table:

```
+-----------+
| id | name |
+-----------+
| 1  | A    | 
+-----------+
| 2  | B    | 
+-----------+
| 3  | C    | 
+-----------+
```

This is product_filter table:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
| id | product_id | filter_id |
+-----------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | 1         |
+-----------------------------+
| 2  | 1          | 2         |
+-----------------------------+ 
| 3  | 2          | 1         |
+-----------------------------+
| 4  | 2          | 2         |
+-----------------------------+
| 5  | 2          | 3         |
+-----------------------------+
| 6  | 3          | 1         |
+-----------------------------+
| 7  | 3          | 3         |
+-----------------------------+
```

i want if where product_filter.filter_id = 1 and product_filter.filter_id = 2 
the result of product.id is 1 and 2

if where product_filter.filter_id = 1 and product_filter.filter_id = 3 the result of product.id is 1 and 3

This is my query, and it's not works:

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `product_filter`.`filter_id`
FROM `products` 
JOIN `product_filter` ON `product_filter`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
WHERE `product_filter`.`filter_id` = '1' AND `product_filter`.`filter_id` = '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AND` use `IN`:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    pf.filter_id
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_filter pf
    ON pf.product_id = p.id
WHERE
    pf.filter_id IN (1, 2);
```

Comment: i've tried to change AND to OR, it's make the result came 3 (1, 2, and 3)

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea Did you try the query Tim suggested?

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea Did you try with `IN`

Comment: Ya, it's still same

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea Try with this  pf.filter_id IN (1, 2);